# Using ActiveResource without Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

Hi I'm developing a Rails application that exposes some methods via ActiveResource. I want to access these resources through a simple remote ruby script. I want to know if it's possible use ActiveResource without Rails .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can. ActiveResource is a separate library.
However, ActiveResource depends on ActiveSupport, so make sure you include both as requirements in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible to use ActiveResource separately.

You can find good documentation on the [project page](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activeresource) @ github.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've done it before. But IMO, there are other options out there now that are a little nicer. RestClient and HTTParty come to mind.